# Decoding response body "on the fly" in an Okhttp Interceptor

Tags: retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I'm developing an Android App using Retrofit & OkHttp.

The backend i'm facing is of questionable quality:

It bypasses the http-error-code-system for a "homemade" solution.
Instead of sending the appropriate error code, it returns a `HTTP-200` with a body containing `{ "errorcode" : 404 }`.

Since i can't change the backend, i'd like to cleanup this mess as soon as it enters my app; a Okhttp interceptor seems like the right place:

```
 okHttpClient
     .addInterceptor(responseBodyInterceptor(json))
     [...]
     .build()


@Throws(BackendError::class)
private fun responseBodyInterceptor(json: Json) = Interceptor { chain ->
    chain.proceed(chain.request()).also { response ->
       
        // retrieving the whole body here - similar to the official logging interceptor 
        val body = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE).string()

        val bodyObject = json.parseToJsonElement() as? JsonObject

        val errorcode = (bodyObject?.get("errorcode") as? JsonPrimitive)?.content

        if (errorcode != null) throw BackendError(errorcode)
    }
}
```

I'm now looking for a more elegant way to do this.
My issue here is that i'm parsing the complete network response at once.
I'd like to parse it somewhat similar to a stream. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not, streams can be read once, see https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/#the-response-body-can-be-consumed-only-once . Maybe you could read a bit and stop once you get to the interesting bit? But then you would need to pass the buffer with the read content through to the consumer somehow. Typically if you cant keep it in memory then it would need to paged to disk and re-read from there when processed. Interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom ResponseBody:

```
private fun responseBodyInterceptor(json: Json) = Interceptor { chain ->
    chain.proceed(chain.request()).also { response ->
        val body = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE).string()
        val bodyObject = json.parseToJsonElement(body) as? JsonObject
        val errorcode = (bodyObject?.get("errorcode") as? JsonPrimitive)?.content
        if (errorcode != null) throw BackendError(errorcode)
        else response.newBuilder().body(CustomResponseBody(body, response.body()!!)).build()
    }
}

private class CustomResponseBody(private val body: String, private val originalBody: ResponseBody) : ResponseBody() {
    override fun contentType(): MediaType? = originalBody.contentType()
    override fun contentLength(): Long = body.length.toLong()
    override fun source(): BufferedSource = body.byteInputStream().source().buffer()
}
```

The response body is only read once, when the response is created. The response is then cached and the body is read from the cache. So, if we replace the body with a custom one, the response will be cached with the custom body.